# Floated element's absolute positioned content broke layout and crashes animation

Tags: jquery, html-lists, itunes, css-position

I am creating image gallery and I want to add to each element expanding menu on click.

I want to recreate iTunes 11 album view effect.

I put my images as a grid using html unordered list

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    ...
    <li><div class="box"></div></li>
    <li class="clear"></li>
</ul>
```

Then using jQuery I wrote a function that triggered when I click on li element, adding to its another div, and to this div loads the menu.

```
$("li").click( function() {

    $(this).append("<div class='container'></div>");

    var cont = $(".container", $(this));

    cont.html("<div class='menu'><div class='content'></div></div>");

    var item_height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var cont_height = $(".content", cont).outerHeight();

    $(".content", cont).css({ height:0 });

    $(".content", cont).stop().animate({ height: cont_height + "px" });    

   $(this).css({height: (item_height+cont_height) + "px"});


} );
```

And the major problem is when I click on li element the "iTunes effect" doesn't work - menu appears but without any animation, and to go further it is breaking the whole layout.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/puz219/VmrEG/

Is there any way to fix the animation and itself the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some small changes, also added that only one bar can be open at the same time with

```
.remove()
```

Check it out here **http://jsfiddle.net/VmrEG/3/**

Here the new fiddle with rows. You can add as much elements in a row as you like

**http://jsfiddle.net/VmrEG/6/**

Comment: ok, animation works, but menu should appear between lines, so when I click on first line/row element it should appear betwwen the first line element bottom and the second line element top, not over the second line element, and thats my big issue with this code

Comment: you could wrap for each for a div around the list, and for each row make a new list, then you could push the next row down when clicking an element in a row

Comment: sound like a good idea, but im affraid that my coding abilities are not enough to make this happen

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out and take it as answer if you like :)